# Unifying Receiver Unite Old Keyboard With Mouse

Tags: logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

Here's my situation. I had a wireless mouse and a wireless keyboard. Owing to enthusiastic cleaning of my wife, I no longer have the mouse and I no longer have the receiver for the keyboard. So I am left with the Keyboard and the receiver for the mouse.

The receiver for the mouse is NOT a unifying receiver. But I note that on the underside of the keyboard, the logo for the unifying stuff is present.

So, to my question. If I buy a wireless mouse with a unifying receiver, and download the unifying software, will I be able to get my old keyboard and the new wireless mouse both running off the same unifying receiver (the one which will come with the new wireless mouse)?

Comment: She got rid of the mouse and receiver completely? Wow, that's enthusiastic cleaning indeed! As for your question, I'm not sure anyone here can give you a definite Yes or No answer.

Comment: @Karan It might be a case of just do it. See what happens. And yes, her over-zealous cleaning drives me nuts and costs me money. Cleanliness is next to godliness is her mantra.

Comment: "It might be a case of just do it. See what happens" - That's precisely what I was driving at. If you're hoping to make your purchase based on someone here saying whether it'll work or not, I would say there's no point. Just buy it, try it and if it doesn't work you can perhaps edit the question then to mention model numbers of all devices and ask whether they can be made to work together somehow or not.

Comment: @Karan That's fair. I'll report back later in the week (or thereabouts).

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note to confirm that the following course of action worked:

I purchased a [new mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/wireless-mouse-m560) with a unifying receiver.

I downloaded the Logitech unifying software and was able to use the simple instructions to set things up so that the unifying receiver is able to drive both the new mouse and old keyboard.

So, keyboard not wasted! Result!!!